# Could answer copy detection be included in the up-vote score for each answer?

Tags: feature-request, voting, upvotes

An idea came to mind today, inspired by the recent April fools of having a limited amount of copy's available to an end-user. I would assume in general that far more people would copy and paste the solution from an answer, then would also up-vote that solution? I know I have been guilty of this on occasion when in a rush!

So, the idea, what if copy (Ctrl-C, like seen in the April fools) contributed towards the up-vote score of an answer? It would not be a 1-1 ratio where every copy means 1 up-vote; but I am sure even on a 10-1 ratio or 100-1 ratio it would still give a good result.

Maybe this kind of information is already tracked somewhere or could be to see what the impact would be?

---

I can see this did not have a whole lot of love, which is perfectly fine, this is why we have discussions!

A followup, and maybe this can be a future request, is a way to see the most copy and pasted questions that have not been reviewed in a few, well years, to see the quality is still there or if they are falling a little behind the times. As was mentioned in the comments, the root cause needs to be solved.

Thank you all for your time and comments.

Comment: mm, don't think that's a good idea: imagine I post a problematic code snippet that every visitor copies just to see where things went wrong. The people copy, check, and it turns out the code is wrong/slow/ineffective - but for some reason the system already placed their upvotes on the post.

Comment: Your idea probably tries to address a very real problem of posts not being voted enough but treats symptoms instead of the root cause by taking the control away from users.

Comment: @OlegValter I agree, which is why I mentioned about it not having the same weight, same can be said about people swooping in, copy, up vote and leave (then realise it was bad..). I would also say this is not to replace the up vote arrows but more compliment them (even in a diminished way).

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow, What If I copied a solution then It didn't work?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand your idea, I just think it's not going to work. The community is also known to react badly to proposals taking away control from the user and making assumptions for them (as indicated by the post score right now).

Comment: I think it is better to try to devise a way to gently nudge users to voting on the post instead. Something like notification popping up in your case (something like "did you find the post useful? If so, don't forget to vote up"). I can see merit in this, it could also work in reducing the number of the "upvote please" comments.

Comment: Why would you assume that *copy* means "I support this answer"? I may copy something to try it. I may also copy an excerprt to use as quote in the comments and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: Lots of daily copies are made to fix formatting and editing issues also. Those are typically on lower quality content and should in no way be used to advance votes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Copying info from an answer is a signal of *something*, but it isn't always guaranteed to be "quality".

To start with, anonymous users copy and paste from this place all the time.  Does it mean that they've got quality code?  [No!  Hardly!  Not even *close*!](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow)

To add on, there is a real endemic of "engineers" copying code from the site and putting it into their code base without really considering what happens afterwards.  Licensing questions gently set aside, the fact that the code that's on the site is old and could contain security bugs is often overlooked.

All of this to say...

## No.  This is a *terrible* idea.

Copying info from an answer is a signal.  It's not going to be a signal of quality.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I think the large text is a little rude, no need to shout it out from the roof tops just because I thought I would try and actively contribute.

Comment: @redorkulated don't mind the header, it's a well-recognized way of emphasis in Meta posts indicating strong agreement / disagreement, nothing directed at you :)

Comment: *Let me copy this answer as an example of  toxicity on Meta* ... Wait! How did I upvote this?

Comment: I copied this answer as an example of why there is far too much [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) on heading styles.